# send data from ajax to codeigniter always fail

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

why my code is always fail to send data from ajax to codeigniter. and i alert these process and not happen..

```
function saveToDatabase(val) {

var datas = 321;

$.ajax({
    url : base_url()+"/Update",
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    data : {datas:data},
    success : function(data) {
        // do something
        alert("pass");
    },
    error : function(data) {
        // do something
        alert("fail");
    }

});
```

and i not come to anything of success or error.. pls help im newbie from ajax. thanks a lot stackoverflow

my controller :

```
public function update()
{
    $account = $this->input->post('account');
    $passwd = $this->input->post('passwd');

    $this->model_site->UpdateTable('1', $account, $passwd);

}
```

my model :

```
function UpdateTable($id, $compname, $industry)
{
    $query = 'Update tb_company set company_name = $compname,      industry_type = $industry where id = $id';
    return $this->db->query($query);
}
```

my routes :

```
$route['my-account/new-account/update'] = 'controller_welcome/update';
```

my url function :

```
function base_url() {
var pathparts = location.pathname.split('/');
if (location.host == 'localhost') {
    var url = window.location;

}else{
    var url = location.origin; // http://stackoverflow.com

}
return url;
```

}

Comment: There is several errors in code. Your AJAX url should be `base_url('my-account/new-account/update')` as I can see. Second, your controller expects POST variables called `$_POST['account']` and `$_POST['password']` but you are sending `$_POST['datas']`. Third, your controller should echo something back to AJAX.

Comment: sorry i forgot to show my base_url func code.. 
i already to show it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function saveToDatabase(val) {
var account = "john";
var passwd = "123";
var datas = {  
              account: account,
              passwd:passwd 
           }

$.ajax({
    url : <?php echo base_url("controller_name/update"); ?>,
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    data :datas,
    success : function(data) {
        // do something
        alert("pass");
    },
    error : function(data) {
        // do something
        alert("fail");
    }

});
```

Your controller function

```
public function update()
{   
    $account = $this->input->post('account');
    $passwd = $this->input->post('passwd');

    // Print Your Post Data At least when sending to update model function.
    $this->model_site->UpdateTable('1', $account, $passwd);

}
```

Comment: i has try ur code but, my code always running to fail .. are u have to trying ?

Comment: just trace or debug your code first . sure you will get result otherwise won't